# Truecrypt and the like - When open are they vulnerable to virus etc.?

Tags: security, encryption, truecrypt

I'm using something like truecrypt now to hold all my login passwords. It opens at start up and mounts as a drive letter just like truecrypt. Now if I can see all these files with my file manager can't a virus or other scanner just access any drive like the file manager and just read everything real easy? What about bit locker or truecrypt used to encrypt the whole drive, sure the drive is encrypted but the person using the computer can see everything but a virus can't, why?

Comment: You chose a suboptimal tool for the use case. For passwords, use something like KeePass2, and do some research regarding possible attacks if you're curious. Encrypting your HDD will only help if an attacker accesses the computer or hdd while it is switched off.

Comment: What if I only mount the truecrypt volume for 30 seconds to extract the password then unmount. It's protected then isn't it?

Comment: Yes after unmounting it, it's protected. However, while it's mounted, you're offering a door that's a million times wider than if you use a password safe.

Answer (score 0):

Malware running in the same context as the user can do the very same things that user can. But malware will typically try to get full system access anyway.

Encryption won't protect your data, because even if something isn't loaded/ready to be decrypted, it can still be destroyed.

That's why offline backups (i.e. physical separation) are important. You can't just 100% rely on software and expect to be safe no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, if you mount encrypted drive it will be exposed the same way as a normal, non encrypted drive. Everything you can access - the same available  for all programs include viruses. It doesn't matter what encryption container are you using(truecrypt (which by the way abandoned) veracrypt(supported fork of truecrypt) or anything else)

As about "why?" - because everything you can do on your computer can be done programmatically